# ExtAudioFileGetProperty fails when ExtAudioFile is converted from AudioFile

Tags: c++, ios, audio

I'm trying to load an MP3 file into an OpenAL buffer, for ios, and I've copied some code from a sample.

So, using this code:

```
    CFURLRef fileURL = nil;
    NSString* nsPath = [CDUtilities fullPathFromRelativePath:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:FilePath.c_str()]];

    if (nsPath) {
        fileURL = (CFURLRef)[[NSURL fileURLWithPath:nsPath] retain];
    }

#if 0
    status = AudioFileOpenURL (fileURL, kAudioFileReadPermission, kAudioFileMP3Type, &AudioFileHandle );
    ExtAudioFileWrapAudioFileID ( AudioFileHandle, false, &ExtAudioFileHandle );

    // Close the AudioFile handle. It's no longer needed
    AudioFileClose ( AudioFileHandle );
    AudioFileHandle = nullptr;

#else
    status = ExtAudioFileOpenURL ( fileURL, &ExtAudioFileHandle );
#endif

    // Get the audio data format
    UInt32 PropertySize = sizeof ( InputDataFormat );
    status = ExtAudioFileGetProperty ( ExtAudioFileHandle, kExtAudioFileProperty_FileDataFormat, &PropertySize, &InputDataFormat);
    if (status != noErr)
    {
        DecodeResult = false;
        goto function_exit;
    }

    if ( InputDataFormat.mChannelsPerFrame > 2 )
    {
        DecodeResult = false;
        goto function_exit;
    }

    // Set the client format to 16 bit signed integer (native-endian) data
    // Maintain the channel count and sample rate of the original source format
    OutputDataFormat.mSampleRate = InputDataFormat.mSampleRate;
    OutputDataFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = InputDataFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;

    OutputDataFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    OutputDataFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 2 * InputDataFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
    OutputDataFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    OutputDataFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 2 * InputDataFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
    OutputDataFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
    OutputDataFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger;

    // Set the desired client (output) data format
    status = ExtAudioFileSetProperty ( ExtAudioFileHandle, kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat, sizeof ( OutputDataFormat ), &OutputDataFormat );
    if (status != noErr)
    {
        DecodeResult = false;
        goto function_exit;
    }

    // Get the total frame count
    PropertySize = sizeof ( FrameCount );
    status = ExtAudioFileGetProperty ( ExtAudioFileHandle, kExtAudioFileProperty_FileLengthFrames, &PropertySize, &FrameCount );
    if (status != noErr)
    {
        DecodeResult = false;
        goto function_exit;
    }
```

In that #if, if I switch it to 1, it will open the mp3 as an AudioFile, and then convert it to ExtAudioFile, otherwise, it opens directly as an ExtAudioFile.

In the first case, for some reason, the later call to ExtAudioFileGetProperty with kExtAudioFileProperty_FileLengthFrames fails with 0xffffffda. It goes ok up to that point. If I open it as ExtAudioFile from the beginning, everything works ok...

I need to open it as AudioFile, because I'm actually using AudioFileOpenWithCallbacks to read from a buffer ( I've already got another mechanism to load the file into a buffer ). If anyone knows any other way to get an ExtAudioFile from a buffer, or even to convert a MP3 buffer to PCM, please share :)

Why does it fail when I open as AudioFile and convert it, but not when I open directly as an ExtAudioFile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the answer. Apparently completely opposing what i've seen in some examples, you cannot release the original handle after converting it to an ExtAudioFile. I moved that AudioFileClose code to the end of the function, and suddenly everything works. I just wonder why everything else kept working with the closed handle but just not that specific property get, but whatever... Apple mysteries :)